# Bootstrap collapse working for first collapse, and show, but then not working afterwards

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

It's strange.. the accordion I've made is copied straight from bootstrap pages. The first time you click on each tab, and expand, and then collapse them, they works fine... However if you try and do it again, they don't respond. What could be causing this? This has been driving me mad all day.

You can see an example of this here - http://v2.marlownailandbeauty.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=133

Markup:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a></div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
             <div class="accordion-inner">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
         <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo"> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a></div>
         <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
               <div class="accordion-inner">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree"> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a></div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the markup would definitely help.

Comment: I don't need to add any javascript calls do I, like $('#myCollapsible').collapse({
  toggle: false
}) .. as it's all activated through the data-toggle parameters? There must be a conflict somewhere I guess, but no errors showing on developer console. I'm pretty amateur at best though :) Doing this for my mum.

Comment: Do I need to change the behaviour from 'collapse' to 'toggle'? (not that i'm sure how to with data attributes setup). The modal window is working OK on the site, and the navbar at the bottom... all css and js is loaded. I guess I've just not got it setup right.. but I thought the example on their site would work... ?

Comment: So far as I can tell, you're not doing anything wrong. Can you do a second test on a "clean" page (no mootools, theme-JavaScript, etc)? Perhaps there's a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla includes Mootools by default, removing Mootools solved this **exact** situation for me.

You can remove Mootools this way:

```
<?php $headerstuff = $this->getHeadData();
foreach ($headerstuff['scripts'] as $k => $item) {
    if(stristr($k, 'mootools-core.js')) unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
    if(stristr($k, 'mootools-more.js')) unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
}
$this->setHeadData($headerstuff); ?>
```

I have tried installing jQuery Easy plugin, but it does not resolve the issue.